# With Headless nothing happens and without Headless it collects the data perfectly in both webdriver.chrome and webdriver.firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The idea would be to literally do the same keyboard work:

> Step 1 -> Open Web Page
>
> Step 2 -> Ctrl + A (Select All)
>
> Step 3 -> Ctrl + C (Copy)

Here's how I use it for `Chrome`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip
import time

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)

link='https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=21150687'
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(10)
element=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'c')
driver.quit()
alltext=pyperclip.paste()

print(alltext)
```

Here's how I use it for `Firefox`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pyperclip
import time

option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

link='https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=21150687'
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(10)
element=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'a')
element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL,'c')
driver.quit()
alltext=pyperclip.paste()

print(alltext)
```

In both options when `Headless` is not activated, it works perfectly, but when it is activated nothing happens and the script finishes running without anything being delivered.

Is there anything I can do to resolve this?

Comment: Don't you think it is working perfectly. Cuz without really opening webbrowser how can you copy/paste anything from there?

Comment: Hi @Xitiz I'm still learning, I had figured the commands would work too. Would you have any indication on how I could work to achieve the same result but without needing to open the browser on my screen?

Comment: @BrondbyIF you are only copying the content of the webpage then why not you tried with the print(element.text)?

Comment: Thank you very much, in fact there was no need for all the other steps, it solved my need perfectly. But there was an error message before the print, could you tell me if there is something wrong? ```message compression is disabled because 'zlib' bundle is not included"``` Should I worry or just ignore it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to just print the content of the page, So instead of using `send_keys` you can try with the `text`

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("<Path of chromeDriver>",chrome_options=option)

link='https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards- 
football/index.html?eventId=21150687'
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(10)
element=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

print(element.text)
```